# Netbeans and the maven speed penalty

Tags: java, performance, maven, netbeans, compilation

There is a huge speed penalty when working with small code snippets in maven projects using netbeans due to the fact that an external maven process needs to be run each time you execute something like a JUnit test case.

What are the best solutions to that problem? I'm currently using secondary non-maven netbeans Java projects that include the jars of the primary projects by dropping them into a single directory using maven-dependency-plugin. When I'm finished with the code, I move it to the primary project. However, I need to manually set up the classpaths that way. Is there any better way to do that, ie. develop maven projects without using maven?

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238543

Comment: not really a solution to your issue, but have you tried comparing with other IDEs? say intellij idea community edition? have you tried the usual solution (feed it more memory)

Comment: all other IDEs don't support maven 100%. Eclipse has a lot of m2e plugins but they are not complete and it is a mess (IMHO). So you have to decide between slow but "native" maven support in NetBeans or fast but unreliable/messy/complex maven support in other IDEs.......

Comment: well, as a worst-case you could always do your own custom build, add a manually-written pom.xml to it (or build it as well?) and throw in a scripted invocation of the maven install/deploy plugin(s) to "mavenize" the resulting artifacts. my ide of choice is intellij, and even though it doesnt pick up everything from maven it does pick up most of the config. what are you doing in maven that isnt IDE-friendly? maybe there's a way around that